# Navigation Border-Bottom Not Affected By Padding? CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am trying to create a responsive navigation menu with a border-bottom animation on a:hover but when I try to space out the text with padding it affects the borders. Is there any way that I can make the borders not be affected by the padding? If not is there any other way I space out the links? Here is my code:

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 25px;
  color: #151413;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  padding-bottom: 0.125em;
  transition: border-bottom-color 0.75s linear 0s;
}
nav a:hover,
nav a.active {
  border-bottom-color: #151413;
  color: #151413;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#designers">Designers</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you want the border to be exclusively under the text and not underneath the spacings between the texts or around the texts? Did I understand that correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the border to be exclusively under the text and not underneath the spacings between the texts or around the texts then you can use `margin` instead of `padding`. You can even apply a combination of both — looks slightly better in my opinion:

```css
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 23px;
  padding: 0 2px;
  color: #151413;
}
```

Always keep the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model) in mind:

[image: Box model: Content is in Padding is in Border is in Margin]

---

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 23px;
  padding: 0 2px;
  color: #151413;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  padding-bottom: 0.125em;
  transition: border-bottom-color 0.75s linear 0s;
}
nav a:hover,
nav a.active {
  border-bottom-color: #151413;
  color: #151413;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#designers">Designers</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Does using margin affect the responsiveness of the website on other devices such as mobile or smaller screens?

Comment: As far as I know it doesn’t. Your and my code snippet behave identically for smaller screens apart from the border. Generally speaking, `margin`’s and `padding`’s only difference is how the `border` is placed although there are a few things with paragraphs where two margins can collapse into the same margin but I don’t think it applies here.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. I had tried so many things that I was just lost.